# spy-js not capturing from chrome behind a corporate firewall with a proxy

Tags: intellij-idea, gulp

I am not able to capture any information when starting spy-js on Intellij IDEA 15. I think I'm being defeated by proxies. My setup is as follows:

#### system:

OS X version 10.10.5

#### network:

I work behind a corporate firewall with proxy servers. These proxies are set at the system level and also at the bash shell level. HTTP_PROXY, http_proxy, http.proxy etc are all set.

web server: My web server runs on a remote system within the corporate network over port 80

#### gulp:

I run gulp serve-debug to start my local development web proxy. I use browsersync. So I have my website at `localhost:3000`, and this maps to `some-corp-location/ui`

#### spy-js config:

At the moment, it looks like this (though I've thrashed about and tried many things)

[image: spy-js config]

I followed the advice I've found to check `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` and it never shows the spy-js proxy settings, it always only shows the corporate proxy settings. This is why I'm pretty sure I'm getting burned by proxies. I tried looking at the chrome proxy settings to see if I could disassociate it with the system settings, but it wasn't clear if this would work out or not.